# Why isn't my pug file displaying my retrieved data?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, pug

In my index.js file, when I view the data with console.log I can confirm that it has been retrieved. When I try to get that data into my view I get an error saying: 
`"Cannot read property 'feedUrl' of undefined.`

here is what the console.log returns, this data is coming from the backend, and it is the data that I want to show in my view. Specifically the feedUrl attribute:

```
[
  {
    _id: 5ec4580bb82c6c10a07936b6,
    feedUrl: 'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 5ec463ef7dd1c2d7b32a74bc,
    feedUrl: 'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_world.rss'
  }
];
```

Here is the code from index.js that handles this route:

```
// bring in the models I'll be using
let rssLink = require('./models/rssLink')
let rssItem = require('./models/rssItem')

// set up template engine and specify where the views will come from 
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'pug')

// home route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // query data base for links already stored, if any
    rssLink.find({}, function(err, feedlinks){
        console.log(feedlinks)
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.render('index', {
                title: 'Welcome! Please register below',
                feedlinks: feedlinks
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Here is my pug file (the view):

```
block content
    h1 #{title}
    ul each val, i in feedlinks
        li= val.feedUrl
```

Please let me know how to get past this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that how your Pug is actually indented or is that just a transcription error in the question?

Comment: that's how it is indented

Answer (score 0):

It was the indentation. I feel so dumb, but I'm leaving this here just in case anyone else runs into this problem. Here is the correct indentation:

```
block content
    h1 #{title}
    ul 
        each val in feedlinks
            li= val.feedUrl
```